# A faster approach to find local minima in neighbor elements of rows of a matrix in python without for loop

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose that I have a row vector in python, for each entry in a row of matrix, I want to find the smallest value in above row around three neighbourhoods of above row.

Speaking more clear, I want to find this:

M[i,j]=M[i,j]+min(M[i-1][j-1:j+2]

It is obvious that this can be done using two nested for loops, one iterating rows of the matrix and the other one iterate columns of matrix. However, this is very very time consuimng.

I am looking for a way to do this by only for loop in order to optimize my code. Can I do this using pytorch built-in function in order to speedup the process?

I implemented this using 2 for loops as I said, but it is very time consuming, I am looking for a vector-based solution instead of using for loops.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow! Could you post the code using the nested for loops? It will help us understand how you want to manage edge cases (eg what happens to `M[0,0]` or `M[0,1]`?), and allow us to check our answers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your original code is as such:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.random.random((20, 30))

new_M = M.copy()
for i in range(1, M.shape[0]): # First row unaffected
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        new_M[i, j] = M[i, j] + min(M[i - 1][max(0, j - 1) : j + 2])
```

a vectorized equivalent would be:

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

new_M = M
new_M[1:] = (
    new_M[1:]
    + sliding_window_view(
        np.pad(M, ((0, 0), (1, 1)), "constant", constant_values=np.inf)[:-1, :], (1, 3)
    )
    .min(-1)
    .squeeze()
)
```

Let's break it down. What we're doing here is:

- padding the left and right sides of `M` with `np.inf` in `np.pad(M, ((0, 0), (1, 1)), "constant", constant_values=np.inf)` so the `min` operation still works on the edges.
- using `[:-1, :]` to remove the last row, which isn't used anywhere in the formula.
- `sliding_window_view(M_pad[:-1, :], (1, 3))` create an array of shape `(*M_pad.shape, 1, 3)`, where the 3 elements in the last dimension are the 3 elements used for each `min`.

We finally take the minimum, squeeze the result so it's the same shape as `M` with the last row missing, and add it to `M[1:]` as the first row isn't affected.

---

**For pytorch**

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

new_M2 = M
new_M2[1:] = (
    new_M2[1:]
    + F.pad(M, (1, 1), value=torch.inf)[:-1, :].unfold(1, 3, 1).min(-1).values
)
```

Comment: Thanks, there is also an edge in the right boundary that should be considered. I mean `min(M[i - 1][max(0, j - 1) : j + 2])` should be `min(M[i - 1][max(0, j - 1) : min(j + 2,M.shape[1])])`.

Comment: Anyway, Can I implement it using pytorch? seems that pytorch doesn't have this sliding window function.

Comment: See my edited answer above for pytorch. The right-side edge can be safely ignored, as indexes going over simply get ignored, as opposed to negative indexes on the left edge that wrap around.

Comment: About `pytorch doesn't have this sliding window function.`, - but it can wrap numpy constructed view with just 'torch.tensor( sliding_window_view(...) )'

Comment: That's a great point! I'll add the caveat that this technique is only convenient if the original array is in system ram, as it otherwise requires expensive data transfers from and back to the gpu.

Comment: Also, it worth to warn about possible funny things, which could happen on updating data in such view, so one should be careful, thow I successfully used it even with training.